# Converting atan2 Excel code to R, to produce flow direction in Cartesian Coordinates

Tags: r, excel

I have earth flow displacements in two directions, converted to point data, which I am trying to combine for an overall offset direction (point to where the flow is going). I have magnitude in a separate raster file.

I'm trying to convert an old excel code into R so I can work with larger datasets. I have an IF statement in excel which will convert 2 displacements into direction in Cartesian co-ordinates using atan2. I know that Excel and R have opposite argument placements for atan2, so I've swapped them.

Where it gets messy is after atan2, when I need to convert to degrees and "bin" the results in a correct quadrant. Ultimately, I'd like the values in Cartesian coordinates (0 to 360), rather than -180 to 180 (radians).

I've tried running through these already asked questions, but am still lost:

[How to map atan2() to degrees 0-360](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1311049/how-to-map-atan2-to-degrees-0-360)
[Reshaping EPA wind speed & direction data with dcast in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147914/reshaping-epa-wind-speed-direction-data-with-dcast-in-r?rq=1)

Here is my excel code:

(N2 = the displacement in north direction)
(E2 = the displacement in east direction)

```
=IF(
    (ATAN2(N2,E2)*180/PI())<0, 360+(ATAN2(N2,E2)*180/PI()), 
    ATAN2(N2,E2)*180/PI()
)
```

I tried running this in R like this:

```
theta_rad <- atan2(E,N)
if(theta_rad < 0)
    theta_rad +2*pi

theta_deg <- theta_rad*(180/pi)`  # Convert to degrees
```

I've also tried the following, which just crashes R

```
dir <- (theta_rad > 0 ? x : (2*pi + theta_rad)) * 360 / (2*pi)
```

Warnings: 
The condition has length >1 and only the first element will be used.

Comment: `ifelse(theta_deg <0, 360 + theta_deg , theta_deg)` where  `theta_deg <-atan2(E,N)*180/pi`

Comment: would everything after "where" be placed before the other section? sorry.. I'm totally new to R. 
Also I get the error: "no" is missing, with no default

Comment: For the record, I think you misunderstand [Cartesian coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_coordinate_system) (nothing to do with angle) and [radians](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radian) (based on `2*pi` vice `360` for a circle).

Comment: I've never seen the `?` notation for R, where is that defined?

Comment: This really seems like a modulos operation (`%%` in R), not an `ifelse`. For example, `(360+c(-180,-90,0,90,180)) %% 360`.

Comment: What I want is direction that can be read by a GIS program, where North=0, East = 90 etc. In these programs, this is the terminology that they use (and the other option being arithmetic).

Comment: What makes you think that this is not the case? If you give sample data and expected output, there's a better chance of getting what you need. (... and what do you mean, "arithmetic" as an alternative to degrees? I'm feeling a bit dense at the moment.)

Comment: hi @r2evans! Ok, so what I mean is that in mathematical terms, 0 is usually point "right" for lack of a better description. I needed to force 0 to be pointing "up" - or if you think of a compass, it would be where North is, 90 = east, 180 = south etc.

Comment: Ok, I understand that. What makes you think that this is not the case?

Comment: When I would test my results against known motion direction, these results did not make sense. I was able to "force" 0 to = N by flipping the inputs of atan2 in R. instead of atan2(y,x), it becomes atan2(x,y). These results made more sense when I compared it to known values

Answer (score 2):

Because `atan2` returns on the domain of `(-pi,pi]` but you want it starting at 0 instead (`(0,2pi]` in radians), then modulus works for you here.

```r
cbind(a=seq(-pi, pi, len=11), b=(2*pi+seq(-pi, pi, len=11))%%(2*pi))
#                a         b
#  [1,] -3.1415927 3.1415927
#  [2,] -2.5132741 3.7699112
#  [3,] -1.8849556 4.3982297
#  [4,] -1.2566371 5.0265482
#  [5,] -0.6283185 5.6548668
#  [6,]  0.0000000 0.0000000
#  [7,]  0.6283185 0.6283185
#  [8,]  1.2566371 1.2566371
#  [9,]  1.8849556 1.8849556
# [10,]  2.5132741 2.5132741
# [11,]  3.1415927 3.1415927
```

Converting this to degrees is just doing the standard conversion. I think your code should be

```r
(360 + atan2(E, N) * 180 / pi) %% 360
```

Comment: bmn018, does this answer your question? If it doesn't give you the output you were expecting, it would help if you can provide sample data.

Comment: Hi r2evans, I also cannot make it work for the ff: I would like to find the azimuth at origin (0,0 for delta(1,1) should be 45 (inside quadrant 1), azimuth for delta(1,-1) should be 135 (inside quadrant 2, azimuth for delta(-1,-1) should be 225 (inside quadrant 3), and azimuth for delta(-1,1) should be 315 (inside quadrant 1). Where delta(x,y) = pt(x,y) - pt(0,0)

Comment: @JunFolledo, I see no issue. `(360 + atan2(c(0,1,1,-1,-1),c(0,1,-1,-1,1))*180/pi) %% 360` (your origin plus four quadrants) returns `c(0, 45, 135, 225, 315)` as you expect.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, thank you for your response, pls see my post below.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your response. Based from your code, I was able to come up with an azimuth function as shown below. But I do not understand why I have to use either 450 or 90 on the `add.degree` variable:

```
add.degree <- ifelse(delta.xy[1] < 0 & delta.xy[2]>0, 450, 90)
return(add.degree-deg(atan2(delta.xy[2],delta.xy[1])))
```

Notheless, I found out later that the st_azimuth is now available as:
`nngeo::st_azimuth(st_point(.start),st_point(.end))`

```
# quadrant 1
.start <- c(100.805, 79.600)
.end <- c(123.389, 123.400)
azimuth(.start, .end)
# [1] 27.27638

# quadrant 2
.start <- c(100.805, 123.400)
.end <- c(123.389, 79.600)
azimuth(.start, .end)
# [1] 152.7236

# quadrant 3
.start <- c(123.389, 123.400)
.end <- c(100.805, 79.600)
azimuth(.start, .end)
# [1] 207.2764

# quadrant 4
.start <- c(123.389, 79.600)
.end <- c(100.805, 123.400)
azimuth(.start, .end)
#[1] 332.7236

azimuth <- function(v.origin, v.ending) {
  delta.xy <- v.ending - v.origin
  add.degree <- ifelse(delta.xy[1] < 0 & delta.xy[2]>0, 450, 90)
  return(add.degree-deg(atan2(delta.xy[2],delta.xy[1])))
}
```